# Laravel Blade Hot Refresh With Vite not working

Tags: laravel, vite

I have a fresh Laravel 9 installed. I have run `npm install`, included     `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` in the head tag, and started the vite server but when I change something in the `welcome.blade.php` the page doesn't refresh and I'm not getting any errors. I've checked out the documentation but I haven't noticed missing anything.

Vite config file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: vite manages your JS/TS files, there's no way to hot refresh blade files as far as I know since those are .php files

Comment: @apokryfos Maybe I misunderstood the docs which states, `when building Blade based applications, Vite can also process and version static assets that you reference solely in Blade templates.`. Kindly check out this part that I think means we can do that with vite. 
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#working-with-blade-and-routes

Comment: @apokryfos They also talk about refresh on saving blade files https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#blade-refreshing-on-save

Comment: @apokryfos When you add the `@vite` directive it reloads the page on the browser so it is refreshed. This should have worked. But if anybody else is here with the same issue make sure you have inserted the `@vite(...)` directive with the appropriate entry points in the right file you are loading in the browser. This is usually(but not necessarily) the `welcome.blade.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and it turns out the `welcome.blade.php` file does not have the `@vite(...)` directive.

If you change a blade file that uses the layout files (`guest.blade.php` or `app.blade.php`), which have the `@vite(...)` directive, then the change will be reflected in the browser once the file is saved.

(Thank you to Billion Shiferaw for his comment above which steered me in the right direction.)

Answer (score 0):

Only if you are sure that all your configuration is fine, then **the problem could be related to the path name**.

> Avoid using symbols in the names of the folders that contain your
> project.

E.g. in my case hot reload didn't work because a folder containing my project had these symbols `(`, `)`, then when I deleted them it worked.

**Before:** `./(container foler)/laravel-project` *(no work)*

**After:** `./container folder/laravel-project` *(works)*